# Linux: serial port forwarding via RDP to Windows machine

Tags: linux, windows, rdp, redirection, serial

I'm trying to redirect serial device on /dev/ttyUSB0 to RDP session with Windows (XP or server 2003) through FreeRDP or rdesktop.

Like this for example:
xfrerdp /a:serial,COM3,/dev/ttyUSB0 /v:server 
rdesktop -r comport:COM4=/dev/ttyUSB0 server

At Windows I'm able to see this port. And even if I connect second and third contacts of COM port (just enabling echo to send all the output back to input) I can see echo in Hyper Terminal. But when I connect device I can't use it. It seems that the input in program differs from the output of the COM-device.

What settings and params should I use (like setserial or stty) to configure COM port on Linux similar to COM port on Windows to be able to transfer correct data between these two machines?